# Homework Help. Probability Density Functions.

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, random-variables

$X$ is $N(10,1)$. Find $f(x|(x-10)^2 < 4)$

This is a homework question. I can only figure out that X is normally distributed with mean 10 and variance 1.

Can you please explain what is meant to be found here.

Thanks.

Comment: I would start by first analyzing the condition.  Under what conditions is $(x-10)^2<4$

Comment: Thank you very much. So it means I have to find the probability that x lies between 8 and 12 in the given normal distribution?

Comment: that is correct.  This is a case of substitution.  The expression on the right hand side is basically telling you what you need to do to x in this "given" situation.  SInce the variables are the same, it is simplys substitution.  Again, intuitively, if I told you that f(x,y)=2xy and I told you to find f(x,y) given x=4, then it is simply our task to find f(4,y).  Here we are happy that we only have one variable and so all we need to do is find f(x|8<x<12).  Be careful though here, because you didn't ask for probability.  Your problem says find f(x|(x-10)^2<4), not P(X..)

Answer (score 1):

It is best to rewrite $\{x\;|\;(x-10)^2<4\}$ as  $\{x\;|\;-2<x-10<2\}$. In terms of the normalized quantity $z=(x-\mu)/\sigma$  this is  $\{z\;|\;-2<z<2\}$.

I don't know what $f$ is doing in this problem. If what you really meant was  $P\{x\;|\;(x-10)^2<4\}$, then a table of probabilities for $z$-scores is all you need.